# Get Dynamic Control Value

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

In my Project i have one form Like `default.aspx` and user Control.

in default page i register my user control and when i click on Button then user control render dynamic in place holder. like that :

```
 protected void btnrender_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pldefault.Controls.Add(LoadControl("ucControl.ascx"));
    }
```

In User control i have button, textbox and literal when i enter any value in textbox then it will show in literal.

I know it is simple but when i enter any value in user control text box and then click on button then my page is refresh and my user control gone visible off.

I used update panel but enable to get my value.

Comment: btnrender_Click is way too  far event to enter a "rememberd" control. dynamic controls should be added in the init phase.

Comment: but it is conditional based when i click on btnrender_Click then different2 use control render as run time according to my condition